# How to npm publish an Angular2 Component with separate templateUrl html file?

Tags: angular, npm

I am building a Angular2 library that defines some Components. I am trying to publish this library as an `npm` module and then `npm install` and use it in my other Angular2 projects.

I followed tutorials like [[1]](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-create-an-angular-2-library-and-how-to-consume-it-jspm-vs-webpack/) and [[2]](https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435#.r3w0q7t63). This got me to a point where I can successfully import Services and Components that define their template inline (like `template: '<p>hello world</p>'`) from my library.

However, when I import Components that define their template in a separate file using `templateUrl: 'app/hello-world.component.html'`, my app that is importing this component tries to load the template file relative in my project directory rather than in the `node_modules/` directory of the installed library. Obviously this results in an error:

> 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/app/hello-world.component.html

**Is there a way to publish an Angular2 library that uses `templateUrl`s in Components?
Or is there a workaround, like a tool that can automatically inline any templateUrl references when transpiling my TypeScript Components to JavaScript?**

In case this is relevant: I am currently using SystemJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inlining templates is important for performance reasons also, so it does make sense to get them inlined before publishing a package. Only for quick development it is a hurdle.

My solution is to use the gulp extension `gulp-inline-ng2-template` to create an inlined version of my code and reference the library in the `dist` rather than the `app` folder from my other projects.

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    inlineNg2Template = require('gulp-inline-ng2-template');

gulp.task('inline-templates', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({useRelativePaths: true, indent: 0, removeLineBreaks: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: This one actually works, but i lost more than half hour for using realtive paths for templates, and finally found problem that `UseRelativePaths` should be *camelCase* instead of *PascalCase*.