# Angular2 - Library component with separate template/style files

Tags: javascript, angular, rollupjs

I'm working on a third party module with (currently) a single Component. Currently I have the template and the relatively lengthy style rules inline in the `@Component` annotation however this is becoming unmanageable. I have tried breaking the code out into separate files (`.component.html`) however when I run the build process and attempt to use the component within my test application the template 404s.

1. Can I break the template out to a separate file (even if a build step inserts the template's content into the Component annotation).
2. Can I do the same with the CSS?
3. Is there a way I can replace the CSS with SCSS, and have it compile that CSS prior to inserting the code into the Component annotation?

For reference I'll include the configuration files below, please let me know if anything else would be helpful!. The general structure of the app is unchanged from [this resource](https://medium.com/@OCombe/how-to-publish-a-library-for-angular-2-on-npm-5f48cdabf435#.962kq9cos) ([Github repository for the library](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate)). I created the project by cloning the repository and removing/replacing references to form a base.

**Edit**
I have seen [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941245/how-to-npm-publish-an-angular2-component-with-separate-templateurl-html-file) however if possible I would like to avoid having to also integrate gulp into the build process.

```
// package.json scripts

"scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rimraf dist/bundles dist/src dist/index.d.ts dist/index.js dist/index.js.map dist/LICENCE dist/README.md",
    "bundling": "rollup -c",
    "minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundles/ic-datepicker.umd.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --comments --output dist/bundles/async-local-storage.umd.min.js",
    "copy": "copyfiles LICENSE README.md dist",
    "build": "npm run cleanup && ngc && npm run bundling && npm run minify && npm run copy"
  },

// rollup.config.js
export default {
  entry: 'dist/index.js',
  dest: 'dist/bundles/ic-datepicker.umd.js',
  sourceMap: false,
  format: 'umd',
  moduleName: 'ng.icDatepicker',
  globals: {
    '@angular/core': 'ng.core',
    '@angular/common': 'ng-common',
    'rxjs/Observable': 'Rx',
    'rxjs/ReplaySubject': 'Rx',
    'rxjs/add/operator/map': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/pluck': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/operator/first': 'Rx.Observable.prototype',
    'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/merge': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/throw': 'Rx.Observable',
    'rxjs/add/observable/of': 'Rx.Observable'
  }
}

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@angular/core": ["node_modules/@angular/core"],
      "rxjs/*": ["node_modules/rxjs/*"]
    },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015", 
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
      "index.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

**Edit**

```
// Component decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'ic-datepicker',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  template: `
    <!-- HTML Template -->  
  `,
  styles: [`
    // CSS styles
  `]
})
```

When I replace the `template` with `templateUrl: './ic-datepicker.component.html'`, which is a HTML file at the same level as the component class, I get the following error in the app that imports this module (post build);

[image: 404 console error]

Comment: Could you post the component declaration?  You should be able to reference styles and templates from different files with the templateUrl and styleUrls properties.

Comment: I added the Component decorator, assuming that is what you meant @chrispy, relatively straightforward

Comment: Also - in my main app I have all of my components using `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` - the reason that is not working in this component must be due to the rollup build process, so I don't know how to _insert_ the template contents into the component on build

Comment: I put a snippet below -- try using the full path to the template, starting from the directory the app is served from.  If it lives at the root level, try removing the "./" at the beginning.

Comment: If you know where it is served to, you can specify that path directly, so you could check the file structure in-browser and use that path.

Comment: What are you using to build your application?  If you are using something like the angular-cli or webpack or browserify you should be able to add `moduleId: module.id` to the `@Component` declaration so that the build tool understands the relative path

Comment: @chrispy The path is correct as you say, since the template is at the same level (and at the root). Removing the `./` prefix causes the same error.

Comment: @DaveV I'm using the same build process as in [this app](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) which uses rollup then minifies. That generates a UMD module. (You can see the tasks/commands in the package.json scripts block above if that helps)

Comment: @JamesCrinkley Did you figure out how to do it without first using gulp to inline it and then ngc'ing the .ts files? I am currently stuck at the same problem, and I already spend several full days into getting a library with a component npm'able so that it works with a cli project both with jit and aot compilation. 
Strangely enough, aot works, while jitting doesn't :(

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the full path to your html as such:

```
// Component decorator
@Component({
  selector: 'ic-datepicker',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: "approot/ic-datepicker.component.html"
})
```